# How can one go from Woodlands Checkpoint to Little India in Singapore with public transportation between 1 and 5 am?

Tags: public-transport, borders, singapore, night-transport, timetables

[SBS Transit Bus Service 170](https://landtransportguru.net/bus170/) seems convenient but it does not operate between 00:40 am and 05:20 am: the last bus departs at 00:30 am from Larkin station at shown in the table below and I assume it takes about 10 minutes at night to reach Woodlands Checkpoint bus station.

[image]

(Source of the table: https://landtransportguru.net/bus170/)

Meanwhile, the MRT also does not operate between ~00:45 am and ~05:30 am, and the MRT stations are anyway a bit far from the Woodlands Checkpoint. E.g., the [Thomson–East Coast MRT line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomson%E2%80%93East_Coast_MRT_line) aka brown line ([map](https://www.lta.gov.sg/content/ltagov/en/getting_around/public_transport/rail_network/thomson_east_coast_line.html) ([mirror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oViOY.jpg))) has its last train departing Woodlands MRT stations at ~00:45 am:

[image]

(Source of the table: http://journey.smrt.com.sg/journey/station_info/woodlands/first-and-last-train/)

How can one go from [Woodlands Checkpoint](https://maps.app.goo.gl/2jqczfgacKyy8Dn57) to [Little India](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Little+India,+Singapore) with public transportation between 1 and 5 am? Did I miss some option or do I have to take some ride-sharing application such as Grab?

Comment: Searching on Google Maps gives no routing after last 170

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Late-night public transport in Singapore [has largely been suspended](https://mothership.sg/2022/06/sbs-transit-to-discontinue-nite-owl-bus-services-from-june-30-2022/) effective June 30, 2022.

However, if your goal is to come from Johor Bahru and not merely the Woodlands checkpoint itself, there appears to be limited overnight service [available](https://mothership.sg/2022/08/24-hour-bus-singapore-jb/) on the [CW2 Bus](https://www.causewaylink.com.my/routes-schedules/?view=timetable&no=CW2&line=Inbound&origin=JB%20Custom%20IN&dest=Queen%20Street%20Terminal) to Queen Street bus terminal, not far from Little India.

Comment: There was also a shortlived Shenton Way to Woodlands service run by the private A&S Transit in Jan-Jun 2023 ( https://sg.news.yahoo.com/singapore-late-night-bus-services-restart-private-company-090518426.html https://www.facebook.com/anstransit/posts/pfbid0RDpYVGj5G3Y6tp5yqKFf91Ww3HC5VEbtuCMMhSQVkMjfC2G6Pe91oue7g2VhkJJDl). Generally there's not enough demand for late night transport and hence also no supply.

Answer (score 7):

As a complement to [mlc](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/94507/mlc)'s answer, the CW2 bus can be taken all night long at the Woodlands checkpoint. To take it, after passing the Singapore immigration, go downstairs: you'll see many buses, and the CW buses are at the end of the bus station (i.e., walk straight and you'll see the yellow signs for the CW1 and CW2 buses). One can use cash, visa cards and some other means of payments. Maybe some other buses also go near Little India, I don't know.